# Select ten recent review comments from ten different users

Tags: mysql, database

I have two database tables, `Users` and `Review`. The `User` table has a reference key to the `Review` table.

```
User table  
----------
userid  
name  
password  
email  

Review Table
------------
reviewid  
userid  
comment  
datetime
```

I am using mysql database

I want to query 10 recent user review comments without repeating the same user in case where are user have 4 most recent reviews.  So in effect the 10 result will be from different users.

How do I do this?

Comment: It would help if you showed us the query you tried, even if it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  SELECT *, COUNT(*) reviews_no 
    FROM review
GROUP BY userid
  HAVING reviews_no > 4
ORDER BY datetime DESC
   LIMIT 10
```